# With C# Websocket4Net, is there a way to add request headers when connecting?

Tags: c#, websocket4net

I tried looking everywhere for the solution, but I wasn't able to find out how to do it.

```
WebSocket websocket = new WebSocket("wss://url.com");

//How would I add custom headers around here, like User-Agent etc?

websocket.Opened += (sender1, e2) =>
{
    MessageBox.Show("Connected to WebSocket server");
};

websocket.Open();
```

I tried looking around and hopped around 2-3 different websocket packages but it seems like they all either couldn't handle my websocket connection properly or they didn't support custom headers. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Question kinda doesn't make sense; you talk as if there is a standard set of headers applicable to a websocket connection, but there isn't. There might be headers before, where an HTTP connection is upgraded to web socket, and HTTP headers are communicated as part of the deal, but those are HTTP headers; after the connection becomes websocket it's more like a raw socket connection and different protocols (standard or bespoke) are implemented as different shaped messages. There are subprotocols but they don't feel like what you're asking for.. Do tell us if you think otherwise though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add custom headers with **WebSocket4Net**, you can pass them in the constructor of the **WebSocket** instance:

```
WebSocket websocket = new WebSocket("wss://url.com", customHeaderItems: new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> {
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("User-Agent", "YourCustomUserAgent"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Another-Header", "HeaderValue")
});
```

If **Websocket4Net** does not support this directly in the version you're using, or if the constructor does not allow custom headers, you may need to check the documentation or repo for the version you're using.